Blazor component @inject not working while dependency registered in client project program.cs file
I have created a very simple Blazor application, which have BlazorTestApp and BlazorTestApp.Client. I want to inject HttpClient in the BlazortestApp.Client>Pages>Counter.razor.
Following is the simplified version, and I have used HttpClient as an example, but in real scenario, I want to have my own object to be injected.
@page "/counter"
@rendermode InteractiveAuto
@inject HttpClient Http

<h1>HttpClient test</h1>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="GetData">Get Data</button>

@code {

    private async Task GetData()
    {
        var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1";
        using HttpResponseMessage response = await Http.GetAsync(url);
        var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }

}

I registered the the dependency in the BlazorTestApp.Client>Program.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
//Registering the HttpClient Dependency
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient());

await builder.Build().RunAsync();

When I navigate to that page, I am getting following exception.
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property 'Http' on type 'BlozorTestApp.Client.Pages.Counter'. There is no registered service of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient'.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<CreatePropertyInjector>g__Initialize|1(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IComponent component)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.InstantiateComponent(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Type componentType, IComponentRenderMode callerSpecifiedRenderMode, Nullable`1 parentComponentId)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InstantiateChildComponentOnFrame(RenderTreeFrame[] frames, Int32 frameIndex, Int32 parentComponentId)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewComponentFrame(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 frameIndex)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewSubtree(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 frameIndex)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InsertNewFrame(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 newFrameIndex)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.ComputeDiff(Renderer renderer, RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, Int32 componentId, ArrayRange`1 oldTree, ArrayRange`1 newTree)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment, Exception& renderFragmentException)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.AddToRenderQueue(Int32 componentId, RenderFragment renderFragment)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.StateHasChanged()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallOnParametersSetAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.SetDirectParameters(ParameterView parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderRootComponentAsync(Int32 componentId, ParameterView initialParameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.HtmlRendering.Infrastructure.StaticHtmlRenderer.BeginRenderingComponent(IComponent component, ParameterView initialParameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Endpoints.EndpointHtmlRenderer.RenderEndpointComponent(HttpContext httpContext, Type rootComponentType, ParameterView parameters, Boolean waitForQuiescence)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Endpoints.RazorComponentEndpointInvoker.RenderComponentCore(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Endpoints.RazorComponentEndpointInvoker.RenderComponentCore(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RendererSynchronizationContext.<>c.<<InvokeAsync>b__10_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

If I do the dependency registration in BlazorTestApp>Program.cs then it works.
My question is, as this is a client-side (InteractiveAuto or InteractiveWebAssembly) component, can we not have this dependency registration only in BlazorTestApp.Client>program.cs

rendermode InteractiveAuto will render the component in 3 different states SSR Server Side and Client in that order usually. Even when the client has the component downloaded ready for wasm it will still render on the server first.
The methods I have used are injecting by common interface with different implementations, another is injecting the service provider itself and the service/component gracefully determine the recourse availability.
Use the render modes constructor
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0#prerendering

I encountered similar issue. In my case the method was executing twice, the first time from the server project then from the client project.
Change this
@rendermode InteractiveAuto

to this:
@rendermode @(new InteractiveAutoRenderMode(prerender: false))


Yes this solves the initial problem, but setting prerender to false, lead application to stuck for a while, and it became a very bad UX.
